# substitution matrix based on spatial autocorrelation transformation

Tags: r, matrix, substitution, traminer

I would like to measure the hamming sequence similarity in which the substitution costs are not based on the substitution rates in the observed sequences but based on the spatial autocorrelation within the study area of the different states (states are thus not related to DNA but something else).

I divided my study area in grid cells of equal size (e.g. 1000m) and measured how often the same "state" is observed in a neighboring cell (Rook-case). Consequently the weight matrix indicates that from state `A` to `A` (to move within the same states) has a much higher probability than to go from `A` to `B` or `B` to `C` or `A` to `C`. This already indicates that states have a high spatial autocorrelation.

The problem is, if you want to measure sequence similarity the substitution matrix should be `0` at the diagonal. Therefore I was wondering whether there is a kind of transformation to go from an "autocorrelation matrix" to a substitution matrix, with `0` values along the diagonal. By means of this we would like to account for spatial autocorrelation in the study area in our sequence similarity measure. To do my analysis I am using the package `TraMineR`.

Example matrix in R for sequences consisting out of four states (A,B,C,D):
Sequence example: `AAAAAABBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDAAAAAAAAA`

Autocorrelation matrix:

```
A = c(17.50,3.00,1.00,0.05)
B = c(3.00,10.00,2.00,1.00)
C = c(1.00,2.00,30.00,3.00)
D = c(0.05,1.00,3.00,20.00)
subm = rbind(A,B,C,D)
colnames(subm) = c("A","B","C","D")
```

how to transform this matrix to a substitution matrix?

Comment: Please explain how you derive your substitution costs from your spatial autocorrelation. Anyway, I cannot figure out why you would assign a cost for substituting a state to itself.

Comment: The matrix gives the probability that a location will be of a certain state in case you put random points in the area and is expressed as a percentage. The goal is that substitution costs are derived by those spatial autocorrelation-values. In the example matrix the sum of all substitution rates should sum to 100.

Comment: Since the provided matrix is NOT a substitution cost matrix, I suggest you edit the question to make it clear what it is. As is, the question is unclear and I therefore down voted it.

Answer (score 1):

First, TraMineR computes the Hamming distance, i.e., a dissimilarity, not a similarity.

The simple Hamming distance is just the count of mismatches between two sequences. For example, the Hamming distance between `AABBCC` and `ABBBAC` is 2, and between `AAAAAA` and `AAAAAA` it is 0 since there are no mismatches.

Generalized Hamming allows to weighting mismatches (not matches!) with substitution costs. For example if the substitution cost between `A` and `B` is 1.5, and is 2 between `B` and `C`, then the distance would be the weighted sum of mismatches, i.e., 3.5 between the first two sequences. It would still be zero between one sequence and itself.

From what I understand, the shown matrix is not the matrix of substitution costs. It is the matrix of what you call 'spatial autocorrelations', and you look for how you can turn this information into substitutions costs.

The idea is to assign high substitution cost (mismatch weight) when the autocorrelation (a rate in your case) is low, i.e., when there is a low probability to find say state B in the neighborhood of state A, and to assign a low substitution cost when the probability is high. Since your probability matrix is symmetric, a simple solution is to use $1 - p(A|B)$ for all off diagonal terms, and leave 0 on the diagonal for the reason explained above.

```
sm <- 1 - subm/100
diag(sm) <- 0
sm
```

For non symmetric probabilities, you could use a similar formula to the one used for deriving the costs from transition rates, i.e., $2 - p(A|B) - p(B|A)$.